# Автоматическая отправка информации от бота в таблицу Google SpreadSheets

Tags: python, telebot, google-spreadsheet

Делаю Бота в Телеграм по брони ПК для Компьютерного клуба. Необходимо что бы данные которые ввел пользователь выводились в Google SpreadSheets.
Пробовал метод из данного поста: [https://muxtarovich.medium.com/делаем-бота-для-учета-личных-расходов-на-python-используя-google-spreadsheets-часть-2-ee17e859e1](https://muxtarovich.medium.com/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-google-spreadsheets-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2-ee17e859e1)
Но данные необходимо вводить через дефис, что мне категорически не подходит.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Забронировать")
def reserve(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Обычный зал", "VIP зал", "Playstation", "Вернуться в главное меню")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выбери то что тебе нужно", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text in ["Обычный зал", "VIP зал"])
def type_hall(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер ПК:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_number)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text == "Вернуться в главное меню")
def back_to_mm(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Забронировать")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в главное меню", reply_markup=markup)


def input_number(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        pass
        # message.text тут будет значение которое ввел юзер.
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка! Вы ввели не число.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_number)


@bot.message_handler()
def take_all(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="На такую комманду я не запрограммировал..")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: А как вам подходит?

Comment: Необходимо что бы пользователь нажимал кнопку, и вводил необходимые данные по очереди.

Comment: Если я пойму как выводить в таблицу например номер ПК, то разберусь как выводить и остальные данные